# swift button press action loads tableview controller twice

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a MeterTableviewController connected to two tableview controllers with two segues. The first segue LocationListSegue is connected from a button on the MeterTableviewController directly to the LocationListTableViewController. Another segue MetersListSegue connected from the top of the MeterTableViewController to the
 MeterListTableviewController.

When I press on the location button, the LocationListTableViewController gets loaded twice.
I thought it is because I was calling it twice: once from the button IBAction and another time on Prepare, so I commented the code from Prepare, but it still loads it twice.

However the MeterListTableViewController gets loaded only once.

I dont know why the button press loads the controller twice. Can someone tell me?

```
@IBAction func chooseLocation(_ sender: Any) {
   self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "LocationListSegue", sender: self) 
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        /*
        if segue.identifier == "LocationListSegue"{
            let viewController:LocationListTableViewController = segue.destination as! LocationListTableViewController 
        }
       */
        if segue.identifier == "MetersListSegue"{
            let viewController2:MeterListTableViewController = segue.destination as! MeterListTableViewController

        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you upload storyboard file's screenshot?

Comment: You're calling the segue both from the storyboard, and programmatically. Remove one, and you should be fine. Also, as a practice, I try and stick to calling segues from the storyboard as much as you can, and try and use prepare only to transfer data/perform operations between view controllers. I've always found it more structured that way :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove story board segue and change your code with my code. This is enough for you.

```
@IBAction func chooseLocation(_ sender: Any) {
     let tableViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "your identifier") as! MeterListTableViewController
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(tableViewController, animated: true) 
}
```

If you want to use segue remove IBAction for UIButton and write this code.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == "LocationListSegue"{
        let viewController:LocationListTableViewController = segue.destination as! LocationListTableViewController 
    } else if segue.identifier == "MetersListSegue"{
        let viewController2:MeterListTableViewController = segue.destination as! MeterListTableViewController
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have added a segue as well as segue action from button, remove one of them